# .filter and .map into a function returns?

Tags: json, loops, reactjs

I'm starting with ReactJs and having troubles understanding how to return desired value from a function.

I wrote 1400 code lines to do this simple gym schedule clases ([example here](http://gymnoray.com/horario-clases/)) . Did mostly hundred loops that look the same... I'm sure it's the worst way to do it and for this reason I'm posting it here, with the hope someone can put me into the right direction.
Like this code over and over again:

```
const monday0700= this.state.data.map((clase, index) => {  
  if (clase.dia === 1 && clase.horaclase < "08:00") {
    return (
      <li key={index} className={clase.estilo}>{clase.actividad}
        <p className="duracion">{clase.duracion}</p>
        <p className="sala">{clase.hoy} {clase.sala}</p>        
      </li>
    )
  } else { return false }  
})
```

And then, again a lot of code looking the same in render method:

```
<div className="horario-container">
      <ul className="horario-item">{monday0700}</ul>
      <ul className="horario-item">{monday0800}</ul>
      <ul className="horario-item">{...}</ul>
      <ul className="horario-item">{...}</ul>
      <ul className="horario-item">{...}</ul>
 </div>
```

You can get an idea of this horrible code... but somehow it's working! :O

OK, So after that. I'm working on this function

```
    filtrarClase(dia, hora) {
    let data = this.state.data
    data.filter(clase => {
        if ((clase.dia === dia) && (clase.horaclase === hora)) {
            return clase.actividad
        } else { 
            return false
        }
    })
    .map((clase,i) => {
        console.log(clase.actividad) // OK RECEIVE "SpinBike"
        return (
            <li key={i}>
                <p>{clase.actividad}</p> //NO WORKING
            </li>
        )
    })        
}
```

this let me get a "console.log" with the right results with each call, but printing anything on the page.

```
this.filtrarClase(1,'07:30')
```

Then rendering it:

```
render() {
    const lunes0730 = this.filtrarClase(1,'07:30') // ANOTHER FAIL TRY
    console.log('lunes0730: ', lunes0730) // Returns UNDEFINED

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {this.filtrarClase(1,'07:30')} // NOTHING HAPPENS :(         
        </div>
    )
}
```

But stuck here... 
I will be glad if someone helps me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `filtrarClase` function is not returning anything, use return to return the result from that function.

You are returning the elements inside map body, those elements will be an array elements, you need to return that array from `filtrarClase` function.

Use this:

```
filtrarClase(dia, hora) {
    let data = this.state.data
    return data.filter(clase => {    //use return
        if ((clase.dia === dia) && (clase.horaclase === hora)) {
            return clase.actividad
        } else { 
            return false
        }
    })
    .map((clase,i) => {
        console.log(clase.actividad) // OK RECEIVE "SpinBike"
        return (
            <li key={i}>
                <p>{clase.actividad}</p> //NO WORKING
            </li>
        )
    })        
}
```

Check this snippet:

```js
function withoutReturn(){
   [1,2,3,4,5,6].filter(i => i%2).map(i => i);
}

function withReturn(){
   return [1,2,3,4,5,6].filter(i => i%2).map(i => i);
}

a = withoutReturn();
b = withReturn();

console.log('a', a);

console.log('b', b);
```

Comment: Thanks m8, you did my day better, and also fix the problem.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks again @MayankShukla